# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'CameraManager.Aspect')

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

[image: Related error screen]

I've been getting this error when setting and linking my react-camera with my project on React-Native. I tried all the solutions found in google but still not working, I also tried this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJseuSOC8HA and not working either. Can someone please try to help me?

this is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: Hi. See [this open github issue](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/220). Maybe one of the suggestions and workarounds can help you to solve your case!

Comment: The thing is that you did not rebuild the project..

Comment: hi, did you use CRNA on this case ? I have the same problem but with CRNA

Answer (score 4):

Linked manually the libraries then try again.. We have the same issue and same version I already fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me (after doing all the install steps): react-native link react-native-camera

Comment: did you use expo? or is a react native cli?

Answer (score 1):

use this command.

```
react-native link
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you have cocoa pods
- and you are trying to link package using `react-native link`

Than be sure that you run `pod install` after react-native link